# Why is python shell not printing

Tags: python, printing

I am new to python and writing my first program.   Please forgive my lack of experience and if it is a silly question, my apologies.

I am doing the first exercise in google python tutorial and here is my code that I have put in a new window that I opened from the python 3.3 shell.  This code is directly copied from the solution that gives the answer but my issue is I am NOT SEEING ANY OUTPUT IN THE SHELL WINDOW.   How do I see the output in the shell window.  I am expecting to see something printed based on what I am passing in the main.   What am I missing?

Thanks.

```
def donuts(count):
    if count < 10:
         return 'Number of donuts: ' + str(count)
    else:
         return 'Number of donuts: many'

    return

def main():
    print ('Donuts')
    test(donuts(4), 'Number of donuts: 4')
    test(donuts(9), 'Number of donuts: 9')
    test(donuts(10), 'Number of donuts: many')
    test(donuts(99), 'Number of donuts: many')
```

Comment: Also, why am I not able to paste the code nicely indented so the community can see it as it appears in the shell?  It would be tough for you all to decipher the way it is pasted - I pasted it with the indents but stackoverflow somehow changed it to a compact version that is not clear.

Comment: Please edit your post so that your code is properly formatted.

Comment: There are help files that will tell you how to use markdown. You can also review the edit another user made here.

Comment: Thank you both.  I believe the users' edit are correct.  My code now mimics the formatting I see in the code window of IDLE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
def donuts(count):
    if count < 10:
     return 'Number of donuts: ' + str(count)
    else: return 'Number of donuts: many'

print donuts(8)
```

Comment: Joe -  this worked!  Thanks.  Just as a note though, in python 3.3 the version I am using print command needs to include paranthesis.  So  -  >   print (donuts(8))

Answer (score 1):

Did you invoke the main method anywhere?
Do you have something like this in your python file:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Hi Mariatta - no I don't.   Should I paste this underneath and run it ?  Note the solution below by Joe Ray.   Without invoking the main as you suggest, I was able to get the code to run and display some output by adding print (donuts(8))